# Weighted percentage between two links?

Tags: php, redirect, random, percentage

I'm working with two rotating links in a php redirector, is there a way to weight them in percentages?

For example: The first link will have a 70% chance or getting redirected and second 30%.

Code:

```
    <?php
$k = $_GET['sub'];

$aff[] = 'http://google.com';
$aff[] = 'http://yahoo.com';

srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$random_number = rand(0,count($aff)-1);

$lol = ($aff[$random_number]);
$lal = $lol.$k;

header("Location: $lal");
?>
```

There are similar questions but involve more than two variables.

Comment: Use those solutions that involve more than 2 random items. You might need more in the future and they will also work now with just 2.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
$array = array(70 => "http://google.com",  
               30 => "http://yahoo.com");

$random_number = rand(0, 100);
$last_interval = 0;
$link = "";
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    // in range?
    if($random_number > $last_interval && $random_number < $key + $last_interval) {
        $link = $value;
        break;
    }
    $last_interval = $key;
}

echo "You chose: " . $link;
```

Concept was taken from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/return-random-list-item-by-its-weight and adapted slightly here is a concept that would work. Credit to @Benjamin Kloster who made the original post.

1. Prepare a list of intervals that cover 0 to sum(weights, 30 and 70 in your case). Each interval represents one link, its length being it's weight, so for your example:

   `intervals = [70, 100]`

   Where an index of 0-70 represents link #1, 70-100 link #2.
2. Generate a random number n in the range of
   0 to sum(weights)
3. Find the interval in which n falls and you got your link.

Comment: There's a bug in this code that causes there to not be a "winner" about 3% of the time. The `if` should really be `if($random_number >= $last_interval && $random_number =< $key + $last_interval) {`. [Fixed version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ec841720659c647b008ed275dc5ebaea6d23a8a) vs [original](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/499cbe3ae875a13f099f91d531f472fd24c1bb04)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
$array = array(
     array( 30, 'http://google.de/' ),
     array( 70, 'http://google.com/' )
);



$number = rand( 1, array_sum( array_column( $array, 0 ) ) );
$lastsum = 0;
foreach( $array as $arr ){
    if( $number > $lastsum && $number <=  ( $lastsum + $arr[0] )  ){
        $url =  $arr[1];
        break;
    }
    $lastsum +=  $arr[0];
}
```